# SQL query to get notifications that haven't been disposed

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a CosmosDb container that store notifications that are broadcasted via SignalR. I have stored those 2 notifications:

```
[
    {
        "createdOn": "2019-12-18T09:48:21.4556896Z",
        "disposed": [
            {
                "disposedBy": "anotherAdmin@mail.com",
                "disposedOn": "2019/11/16T12:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "id": "615b9335-f78f-4a53-9e33-74e1b601d8bd",
        "message": [
            {
                "culture": "en-US",
                "key": "Title",
                "value": "Controller notification!"
            },
            {
                "culture": "en-US",
                "key": "Message",
                "value": "This is an info message received from PushNotifications controller!"
            }
        ],
        "target": "administrators",
        "ttl": 86400,
        "_rid": "iNZhANsdVb0XAQAAAAAAAA==",
        "_self": "dbs/iNZhAA==/colls/iNZhANsdVb0=/docs/iNZhANsdVb0XAQAAAAAAAA==/",
        "_etag": "\"0500558f-0000-0d00-0000-5dfa08d00000\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1576667344
    },
    {
        "createdOn": "2019-12-18T09:48:30.4778759Z",
        "disposed": [
            {
                "disposedBy": "admin@mail.com",
                "disposedOn": "2019/11/16T12:00:00"
            },
            {
                "disposedBy": "anotherAdmin@mail.com",
                "disposedOn": "2019/11/16T12:05:03"
            }
        ],
        "id": "287d1ce0-017e-40b5-ab47-9e2222448b33",
        "message": [
            {
                "culture": "en-US",
                "key": "Title",
                "value": "Controller notification!"
            },
            {
                "culture": "en-US",
                "key": "Message",
                "value": "This is an info message received from PushNotifications controller!"
            }
        ],
        "target": "administrators",
        "ttl": 86400,
        "_rid": "iNZhANsdVb0YAQAAAAAAAA==",
        "_self": "dbs/iNZhAA==/colls/iNZhANsdVb0=/docs/iNZhANsdVb0YAQAAAAAAAA==/",
        "_etag": "\"050092b6-0000-0d00-0000-5dfa0c750000\"",
        "_attachments": "attachments/",
        "_ts": 1576668277
    }
]
```

Now I want to create a query to get all notifications that `"target"` is `administrators` and that are **not** disposed by `admin@mail.com`.

I have tried some queries like:

```sql
SELECT value notifications 
FROM notifications JOIN
(SELECT value disposed.disposedBy 
    FROM disposed in notifications.disposed 
    WHERE disposed.disposedBy != "admin@mail.com") 
WHERE notifications.target = "administrators"
```

and

```sql
SELECT value notifications 
FROM notifications JOIN 
(SELECT value disposed.disposedBy 
    FROM disposed IN notifications.disposed 
    WHERE disposed.disposedBy != "admin@mail.com") 
    JOIN (SELECT value notifications 
    WHERE notifications.target = "administrators")
```

and even

```sql
SELECT value notifications
FROM notifications JOIN 
(SELECT value disposed.disposedBy 
    FROM disposed IN notifications.disposed
    WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(disposed.disposedBy, "admin@mail.com"))
```

but none of them give me the expected result that is get only one notification (with Id: 615b9335-f78f-4a53-9e33-74e1b601d8bd).

How can I build this query to get notifications that are for some certain target and where not disposed by certain user?

**Edit 1:** I have figured out how to do this if I change the disposed to an array of string like `disposed: ["user@mail.com", "anotherUser@mail.com"]` using the query

```sql
SELECT value notifications 
FROM notifications 
WHERE NOT Array_Contains(notifications.disposed, "user@mail.com")
AND notifications.target = "administrators"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost get it. Please try my sql:

```
SELECT value notifications 
FROM notifications
WHERE notifications.target = "administrators"
and not Array_contains(notifications.disposed,{ "disposedBy": "admin@mail.com"},true)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking,for, works perfectly! Thank you!